# Programmatically publish unpublished nodes

Tags: nodes, 9

I want to publish unpublished nodes in a custom action. To do this, I query the database on a specific condition and want to use 'exists' condition to find the node IDs to publish. This is the code I am using.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');

foreach($i_selected as $is) {
  $nids = $query->andConditionGroup()
    ->condition('type', 'level3')
    ->condition('title', $file_name)
    ->condition('status', '0')
    ->exists('nid')
    ->execute();

  $nids->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
}
```

I get this error,

> Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Condition::execute()

The SQL query I am trying to achieve is:

```
   select nid, status, title from node_field_data where status = '0' and title = $filename
```

of the result, I want to see if the nids exists and publish those nids.

How do I fix that error?

Comment: Once the question is answered, you cannot change it, not even to add an update basing on given answers. Questions aren't for a back-and-forth with the users who answer.

Comment: I checked you answer only after figuring out on my end. I will make sure to not update questions. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is calling `execute()` on the object returned from `$query->andConditionGroup()`, but that object doesn't implement any `execute()` method.

The correct way to use `andConditionGroup()` is shown in [`QueryBase::andConditionGroup()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryBase.php/function/QueryBase%3A%3AandConditionGroup/9.1.x).

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('drawing');
$group = $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('figures.color', 'red')
  ->condition('figures.shape', 'triangle');
$query->condition($group);
$group = $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('figures.color', 'blue')
  ->condition('figures.shape', 'circle');
$query->condition($group);
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

In your case, using `andConditionGroup()` isn't necessary, as the query executed by that code returns all nodes for which:

- The content type is *level3*
- The title is `$file_name`
- The status is 0

It doesn't return all the nodes for which at least one of those conditions is true. It's similar to what the following code does, which returns all the *page* nodes where the value of *field_some_field* is higher than 14.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'page')
  ->condition('field_some_field', 14, '>');
$results = $query->execute();
```

`$query->execute()` returns an array of entity IDs, not an entity nor an array of entities. `$nids = $query->execute(); $nids->setPublished(TRUE)->save();` is still wrong, as an array doesn't implement the `setPublished()` method.
Given an array of node IDs `$nids`, the correct code to load the nodes is the following one.

```php
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple(array_values($nids));
```

`$nodes` will contain an array of entities. Publishing them can be achieved with the following code.

```php
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
}
```

The object returned from `\Drupal::entityQuery()` verifies the currently logged-in user has view access to the returned nodes. In most of the cases, the user doesn't have access to unpublished nodes. To avoid the query returns only the nodes the currently logged-in user can view, it's necessary to call [`$query->accessCheck(FALSE)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3AaccessCheck/9.1.x), as in `$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->checkAccess(FALSE);`

Furthermore, the `exists('nid')` call isn't necessary, as the node ID is always saved for nodes.

Leaving out the loop on `$i_selected`, the code I would use is the following one.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->checkAccess(FALSE);

$nids = $query->condition('type', 'level3')
  ->condition('title', $file_name)
  ->condition('status', '0')
  ->execute();

$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple(array_values($nids));

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
}
```